# Subtracting time in milliseconds

Tags: python, time

I am trying to time how long it is taking for a sensor to read, but can't get the time part of it to work, what am I doing wrong?

```
import threading
import time

while True:
    program_time = time.time();
    a = program_time
    b = program_time
    c = program_time
    time = c-a
    print time
```

Comment: Why are you importing threading?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are reassigning `program_time` to various variables. They will *not* automatically update their value, you need to call `time.time()` again.

```
>>> import time
>>> time.time()
1361025728.405679
>>> a = time.time()
>>> b = a
>>> b
1361025731.55744
>>> a
1361025731.55744
>>> b - a
0.0
>>> time.time() - b
17.488538026809692
```

You really want to move at least *one* call to `time.time()` outside of your loop:

```
start = time.time()
while True:
    now = time.time()
    elapsed = now - start
    print elapsed
```